# Es posible terminar una funcion map dada una condicion?

Tags: javascript, map, return

Tengo este bloque

```
      await Promise.all(compareDates.map(d => {
          const a = addDays(new Date(d.availability_date), 1).toDateString();
          const b = new Date(date).toDateString();
          if (a === b) {
            found = true;
            return;
          }
        }));
```

El lint me dice que `return;` es redundante, y yo lo que quiero hacer es que una vez `a === b`, salir del map y continuar con el siguiente bloque de código. Si no lo hago puedo seguir iterando entre un montón de elementos innecesariamente.

Intenté reemplazar el `map` por un `for` pero no me estaría funcionando dentro de la promesa.

Edito la pregunta para quienes quieren entender el funcionamiento total de esto:

> La idea es que yo recibo una lista de fechas disponibles de una base de datos, necesito comparar esta lista de fechas con todas las fechas desde hoy hasta dentro de 365 dias. Solo las fechas coincidentes son las que se van a mostrar en el calendario, el resto son fechas deshabilitadas. El componente `react-date-range` solo me permite pasarle un array con `disableDates` asi que tengo que armar un array al "contrario" del que recibo. Entonces comparo, y toda aquella que NO coincida, la agrego a mi array. Asi lo hice:

```
   useEffect(() => {
      const getDisableDates = async () => {
        if (availability?.total_availabilities?.length > 0) {
          const dates = [];
          const compareDates = availability.total_availabilities;

          for (let i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
            const date = addDays(new Date(), i);
            let found = false;

            await Promise.all(compareDates.map(d => {
              const a = addDays(new Date(d.availability_date), 1).toDateString();
              const b = new Date(date).toDateString();
              if (a === b) {
                found = true;
                return;
              }
            }));

            if (!found) {
              dates.push(date);
            }
          }
          setDisabledDates(dates);
        }
      };

      getDisableDates();
    }, [availability]);
```

Comment: puedes probar con una promise clásica que mande resolve() y reject() en lugar de usar await. el resolve si no me equivoco si que es inmediato

Comment: @Grismak y de esta manera me permitiria meterle la sentencia ``for`` adentro de la promesa? o para que me serviria esto? Gracias!

Comment: Siempre puedes crear tu propio map con un for, pero yo creo que tienes un problema conceptual y no es un map lo que estás buscando

Comment: Si, un poco, mira, te paso un ejemplo de una promise con un bucle for dentro: function recargosYDescuentos() {
  var generarExcelRecargosDescuentos = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arraySeleccionados.length; i++) {
   //Aquí dentro puedes hacer lo que quieras y con un resolve() a priori rompes el bucle
  }
 });

Comment: Yo no entiendo la condición. Digamos que `a==b` se da en el último caso, que  esperas como retorno, el array completo?? o tu lo que quieres es obtener el primer caso donde se da `a==b` ???

Comment: @Yussef ahi edite la pregunta comentando todo lo que hice y porque lo hice. Es un for, dentro una promesa y dentro un map. Probablemente lo haya encarado mal.

Comment: @Grismak gracias, voy a ver primero si mi enfoque para solucionar esto está bien, y despues voy a probar tu solucion. Si me sirve te chiflo para que la pongas en las respuestas.

Comment: tranqui, no lo hacemos por los puntos sino por ayudar, si te sirve de referencia ya es suficiente

Comment: Y algo así te funcionará??:  `const b = new Date(date).toDateString();
await Promise.all(compareDates.find(d => b === addDays(new Date(d.availability_date), 1).toDateString());`

Comment: @Yussef gracias, estaba intentando usar lo que me pasaste y justo apareció una respuesta que me funcionó a la perfección. Me tiraba un error que no podia iterar undefined, siendo que compareDates tenia datos, me mostraba el error en ``Promise.all``

Comment: @Grismak tu solución tambien me sirvio, efectivamente ese tipo de promesas aceptan el for adentro, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

siempre puedes guardar todo en un array y procesar después, ejemplo:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
  const date = addDays(new Date(), i);
  let found = false;
  const availabilityDates = [];

    await Promise.all(compareDates.map(d => {
      availabilityDates.push(addDays(new Date(d.availability_date), 1).toDateString());
    }));

    for (const availabilityDate of availabilityDates) {
      const strDate = new Date(date).toDateString();
      if (strDate === availabilityDate) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }

  if (!found) {
    dates.push(date);
  }
}
```

Aunque, me parece más correcto hacer lo siguiente:

```
const getDisableDates = async () => {
  if (availability?.total_availabilities?.length > 0) {
    const dates = [];
    const compareDates = availability.total_availabilities;
    const availabilityDates = [];
    await Promise.all(compareDates.map(d => {
      availabilityDates.push(addDays(new Date(d.availability_date), 1).toDateString());
    }));


    for (let i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
      const date = addDays(new Date(), i);
      let found = false;

      for (const availabilityDate of availabilityDates) {
        const strDate = new Date(date).toDateString();
        if (strDate === availabilityDate) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (!found) {
        dates.push(date);
      }
    }
    setDisabledDates(dates);
  }
};
```